# How to include bootstrap-vue in vue.js with npm?

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, babeljs, bootstrap-vue

I am using vue.js, webpack, npm and jQuery. Now I want to include the framework bootstrap-vue in my project. I followed the guide of https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs via npm and included bootstrap-vue. While starting the build-process of npm, I am getting too many errors with babel-runtime like:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/utils/popover.class.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof' in 
'C:\Users\abdul\WebstormProjects\editor\node_modules\
bootstrap-vue\es\utils'
@ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/utils/popover.class.js 10:38-78
@ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/directives/popover/popover.js
@ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/directives/popover/index.js
@ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/directives/index.js
@ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/index.js
@ ./src/main.js
```

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import 'jquery'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
el: '#app',
router,
template: '<App/>',
components: { App }
})
```

I have similar errors like this for other javascript files. Popover.class.js is one of them.

I except a successful run build with bootstrap-vue. Optional: I could include bootstrap-vue on other ways.

Comment: hey bigiza, welcome to stack overflow, can you please try to delete your whole folder of `node_modules` and then open a new terminal and then run `nam install`...and tell me after how things went :)

Comment: @Ahm. npm WARN rollback Rolling back readable-stream@2.3.6 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat
'C:\Users\abdul\WebstormProjects\editor\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (cur
rent: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})                                                                 
npm run build: same errors like before.

Comment: i think that the problem is that some packages is not downloaded when you `nam install` or that there a problem with the  path that babel using

Comment: can you try to make a `vue.config.js` file in your root folder and add this inside   `const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'bootstrap-components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/components')
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: also if you can add to the post the content of your `babel.config.js` i think it will be helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install vue-cli 3 and add bootstrap-vue as a plugin

Run these commands:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli

vue create project-name

cd project-name

vue add bootstrap-vue
```

The plugin will be automatically added and configured.

Answer (score 3):

Create Project then run this command:

```
npm i bootstrap-vue
```